# Angular, observables generics

Tags: angular, generics, observable

In my controller i am calling the `loginUser` method of my user service and it all works fine,as intended, but i have an error in the terminal. 
The error message i am getting is the fallowing

```
Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<LoginResponse>'.
```

The method i am calling in my controller is the fallowing:

```
  loginUser(form) {
    this.loginModel = form.value;
    this.userService.loginUser(this.loginModel).subscribe((resp) => {
      console.log(resp.id_token);
    });
  }
```

this is the method in my user service

```
  loginUser(loginModel: LoginModel): Observable<LoginResponse> {
    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:8080/authenticate', loginModel);
  }
```

LoginResponse interface

```
export interface LoginResponse {
  id_token: string
}
```

I say it again, the program works, its just that i am getting this error for no reason.

Comment: Not for no reason, you said you were going to return an observable of login response but don't type the response when you make the request: `this.httpClient.post<LoginResponse>(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add typings to your post request.

```
loginUser(loginModel: LoginModel): Observable<LoginResponse> {
  return this.httpClient.post<LoginResponse>('http://localhost:8080/authenticate', loginModel);
}
```

Comment: ok, this did it, but why do i have to put the generic type in both places?

Comment: You do not need to add it in both places. If you remove the return type from your method it will be inferred. By I would keep it in both places as it helps in your code readability.